# Django ManyToManyField in action

Tags: python, django, django-templates, manytomanyfield

I have models.py like this:

```
 class Entry(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
        baslik = models.ForeignKey(Baslik, null=True, blank=True)
        icerik = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return str(self.icerik)

    class Favorite(object):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
        favs = models.ManyToManyField(Entry)
```

And I want to add an entry to a user's favorites' list in template with a link:

```
<div>
            <p>{{ entry}}</p><a href="link">Add to favs</a>
</div>
```

What should I do? I am new at this, so please be explanatory.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I will do in your case:

Creating a view where you add an entry to user fav:

```
def add_fav(request, entry_pk):
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, pk=entry_pk) #Will return you the entry with pk= entry_pk or 404 if does not exist
    #Now we try to check if user already have fav or not
    try:
        favorite = Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user)
    except Favorite.DoesNotExist:
        #If not we create a new favorite object
        favorite = Favorite.objects.create(user=request.user)
    #Then we add the entry to favs
    favorite.favs.add(entry)
    #And we save
    favorite.save()
```

Then you just have to call the view to add the entry as user favorite, so in **urls.py**

```
url(r'^addfav/(?P<entry_pk>\d+)$', 'myapp.views.add_fav', name='myapp_add_fav')
```

And then in your template you can do something like

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp_add_fav' entry_pk=entry.pk %}">Add to favs</a>
```

Hope it was clear

Comment: Thanks for your help but it raised this error: global name 'entry_pk' is not defined

Comment: Just for understand, I have to define add_fav funct in views.py separate from my entry view which links's is /entry/<id> and I put the code with a tags for link, to my html file. and the url code to urls.py file. right?

Comment: Where is the error raised?
Yes define add_fav as a new function in views.py with an other url than /entry/<id> like /addfav/<id>.

Comment: I wrote exact same codes you wrote with a few syntax fixes and then I entered to /entr/1 which I added the "<a href..." code and it says: NoReverseMatch at /entry/1/
Reverse for 'baslik_add_fav' with arguments '(u'entry_pk=entry.pk',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addfav/(?P<entry_pk>\\d+)$']

Comment: There was a typo in what I wrote, should be `"{% url 'myapp_add_fav' entry_pk=entry.pk %}"` (removed the ' after entry.pk)

Comment: now this: NoReverseMatch at /entry/1/
Reverse for 'baslik_add_fav' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'entry_pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['addfav/(?P<entry_pk>\\d+)$']

Comment: It seems entry.pk is not defined. Are you sure entry is in your context?

Comment: When I enter to /entry/1 without the "<a href...>" code. Enter shows up. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No I mean that when you do `"{% url 'myapp_add_fav' entry_pk=entry.pk %}"` entry.pk seems to be undefined. Make sure `entry` variable is defined in your context. You can try to print it with `{{entry.pk}}` and `{{entry}}`

Comment: My entry's name was different and I changed to to 'entry'. In /entry/1 it worked but when I click the link it says: NameError at /addfav/1
global name 'Favorite' is not defined it points to this line: except Favorite.DoesNotExist:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57449/discussion-between-trnsnt-and-user3416136).